# React .map renders whole array each time it is updated and causes duplication

Tags: reactjs

Good day,

I'm trying to map each object array to a `<Label>` component in the render method. Clicking "**Add Annotation**" will add a comment object to the state array of the `<ToolsContainer>` Component. After updating the `<ToolsContainer>` state array, it does a callback function to `<ImageContainer>` which gets the values then updates `<ImageContainer>`'s own state array.

After the update, I mapped `<ImageContainer>`'s state array to the `<Label>` component which works but it is not the way that I wanted it to behave. The problem is that whenever I add another "Annotation" it renders everything in the array which would then cause duplication even though I am using uuids.

Demo Here: https://codesandbox.io/s/lvm1n7w89

- How to use:

  1. Click Get Screenshot
  2. Click any of the screenshot below
  3. Click Add Annotation
  4. You can drag the annotations around

Code Below:
**ToolsContainer.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Button from '../../components/UI/Button/Button'
import uuid from "uuid";

class ToolsContainer extends Component {
    state = {
        isAddingAnnotation: false,
        commentArray: [],
        comment: "",                                                              
        labelCount: 0
    }
    addCommentHandler = () => {
        let comment = {
            uuid: uuid.v4(),
            value: "Insert comment here"
        }
        this.setState({
            commentArray: [...this.state.commentArray, comment]
        }, () => {
            console.log("[ToolsContainer][addCommentHandler] " + this.state.commentArray)
            this.props.getCommentsHandler(this.state.commentArray)
        })

    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="pure-g">
                <Button gridClass={"pure-u-4-24"} buttonName={"Add Annotation"} onClick={() => this.addCommentHandler} />
            </div>

        )
    }
}

export default ToolsContainer;
```

**ImageContainer.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import "./ImageContainer.css";
import { Stage, Layer, Image, Tag, Text, Label } from 'react-konva';
import ToolsContainer from '../ToolsContainer/ToolsContainer';

class ImageContainer extends Component {
    state = {
        showImageContainer: true,
        canvasHeight: 0,
        canvasWidth: 0,
        canvasImageUrl: "",
        image: null,
        commentsArray: [],

    }

    componentDidMount() {
        let stage = this.refs.stage
        const imgObj = new window.Image();
        imgObj.src = this.props.selectedImageURI
        imgObj.onload = () => {
            this.setState({ image: imgObj })
            this.setState({ canvasWidth: imgObj.width, canvasHeight: imgObj.height });
            let canvasImageUrl = stage.toDataURL();
            this.setState({ canvasImageUrl: canvasImageUrl })
        }


    }

    getLabelCount = (count) => {
        this.setState({ labelCount: count })
    }

    displayContainerHandler = () => {
        this.props.showImageContainer(!this.state.showImageContainer)
    }

    downloadImageHandler = () => {
        let a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = this.state.canvasImageUrl.replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
        a.download = 'shot.png';
        a.click();
    }

    onDragEnd(event) {
        console.log(event.target)
    }

    handleDelete = comment => {
        const commentsArray = this.state.commentsArray.filter(c => c.uuid !== comment.uuid);
        this.setState({ commentsArray });
    };

    getCommentsHandler = (comments) => {
        console.log("[ImageContainer][getCommentsHandler] " + comments)
        this.setState({
            commentsArray: [...this.state.commentsArray, ...comments]
        }, () => {
            console.log("[ImageContainer][getCommentsHandler] " + this.state)
        })
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div className="ImageContainer" >
                <button className="ImageContainer-close-button " onClick={this.displayContainerHandler}>[x]</button>
                <Stage ref="stage" height={this.state.canvasHeight * .5} width={this.state.canvasWidth * .5} >
                    <Layer>
                        <Image image={this.state.image} scaleX={0.5} scaleY={0.5} />
                        {this.state.commentsArray.map(comment => (
                            <Label key={comment.uuid} draggable={true} x={150} y={150}>
                                <Tag
                                    fill="black"
                                    pointerWidth={10}
                                    pointerHeight={10}
                                    lineJoin='round'
                                    shadowColor='black'
                                />

                                <Text
                                    text={comment.value}
                                    fontFamily='Calibri'
                                    fontSize={18}
                                    padding={5}
                                    fill='white'
                                />

                                <Text
                                    text="[x]"
                                    fontFamily='Calibri'
                                    fontSize={18}
                                    x={170}
                                    fill='black'
                                    onClick={() => this.handleDelete(comment)}
                                />
                            </Label>
                        ))}

                    </Layer>
                </Stage>
                <ToolsContainer getCommentsHandler={comments => this.getCommentsHandler(comments)} />
                <button className="pure-button" onClick={() => this.downloadImageHandler()}>Download</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default ImageContainer;
```

For those wondering I am using react-konva for this project. 
Any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

Dragging the annotations will show the duplicates

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in this line:

```js
getCommentsHandler = comments => {
  console.log("[ImageContainer][getCommentsHandler] " + comments);
  this.setState(
    {
      commentsArray: [...this.state.commentsArray, ...comments]  // This is the problematic line
    },
    () => {
      console.log("[ImageContainer][getCommentsHandler] " + this.state);
    }
  );
};
```

When you use the spread operator the way you did, you take the existing array content and append all the received data to it, like so:

```js
const a = [1,2];
const b = [2];
const b = [...a, ...b] // b === [1,2,2]
```

You need to change the line marked with comment to look like that:

```js
commentsArray: [...comments]
```

Comment: thanks I was playing around it and eventually got this same answer

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the best way to do it but it works.

The callback function getCommentsHandler returns the array of comments. The solution to this issue is to set the state of commentsArray in the `<ImageContainer>` component to empty before retrieving the state values from the `<ToolsContainer>` component.

The line `commentsArray: [...this.state.commentsArray, ...comments]` is what causes the duplication issue. In the callback function I replaced it with `this.setState({ commentsArray: [] })` then added `this.setState({commentsArray: comments})`